# how to get some part of a string in TCL

Tags: string, tcl

I have a string in tcl like this:

```
set hello 0x09
```

how to get the last part of `$hello`, like `09` from it?

Comment: What have you tried to far? We don't do someone else's homework here but we're pleased to help with concrete problems, so [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please, be more specific and descriptive.

Comment: Well, is the string `0x09` or `set hello 0x09`? If it is `0x09` it is an integer (do what you want with it). If it is the later eval it in a safe interp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer to your question would be:

```
set result [lindex [split $hello "x"] 1]
```

Depending on your problem, this solution might not be the best. What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate the string in a slave interpreter, and rely on the fact that the `set` command returns its value:

```
set cmd {set hello 0x09}
set i [interp create -safe]
set value [interp eval $i $cmd]
puts $value
```

```
0x09
```

This also protects you from `set hello [exec echo malicious command here]`